# Regarding the interval $[a+1/n,b-1/n]$ in $(a,b)$ for all large $n$

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Suppose that we have an interval $(a,b)$. When I draw a line between $a$ and $b$, and then I try to part the interval into something like $[a+1/n,b-1/n]$, where $n$ is a natural number. The problem is, the left endpoint might be greater than the right endpoint. So, the question is:

Is there an justification for, why we can choose an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a+1/n<b-1/n$ for all $n\geq N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $a + 1/n < b - 1/n$, after rearranging, is equivalent to $1/n < (1/2)(b - a)$. Given that $a < b$, we know $(1/2)(b-a)$ is positive. It is a theorem that, for every positive $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an $N$ such that $1/n < \varepsilon$ for every $n \geq N$.

This is an example of the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property), and it can be seen to be true because it is equivalent to the statement "for every real $r$, there is a natural $N$ such that $r < N$".

Answer (score 0):

$a+\frac 1n < b-\frac 1n \iff$

$\frac 1n + \frac 1n < b-a \iff$ (note: $a < b$ was your only assumption)

$2\times \frac 1n < b-a \iff$

$ \frac 1n < \frac {b-a}2 \iff $ (note: $n \in \mathbb N \implies n > 0$ so)

$\frac 2{b-a} < n$.

Now presumably you know that the naturals are not bounded above.  So just pick an $n$ so that $n > \frac 2{b-a}$.

====

Actually, it is a bit more complicated than that.  You do have to prove that the naturals are unbounded in the first place.  That is a consequence of the archimedean property that for any $d> 0$ and any $M \in \mathbb R$ there exists a $n \in \mathbb N$ so that $nd > M$.  (And if we let $d=1$ then "the naturals are unbounded" is an immediate consequence.)

But we have to prove the archimedian property in general and ... that's beyond the scope of your question.